# Home to use OpenFire in Multi Device?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

As installed in linux server OpenFire unable to default work on multi device login with same user id.

I had my desktop and mobile and laptop, want same user id to enable in 3 devices. Default did not work.

How may I enable it ?

Answer (score 0):

http://ejabberd.yourwebsite.com:9090/   OpenFire Admin

In OpenFire Management Panel,

Property Name : route.all-ressources
Property Value : true

[image]